# Trying to embed this video can't find name of videoplayer

Tags: javascript, html, video, embed, video-player

I am trying to mute and auto play this embed video but I don't know what kind of video player is this to add extra tag to do auto play and mute audio.

[This](http://twides.com/advertisment.html) is the link to the player.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching this one:
https://www.mediaelementjs.com/

(Found it through the embedded CSS files)

Link to the API: https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: You are a legend, any idea how can i mute this

<div style="position:relative;padding-bottom:56.25%;height:0;overflow:hidden;"><iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden" frameborder="0" type="text/html" src="https://www.twides.com/embed/RVXucbpjTBEE6N5?autoplay=1" width="100%" height="100%"   allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

Comment: I would say (untested) in the URL you only have to append muted=1.

So your iFrame URL should be: "twides.com/embed/RVXucbpjTBEE6N5?autoplay=1&muted=1

Comment: Yes i have tried just like this but it does not work,everytime i add &muted="1" it shows me a error like this http://prntscr.com/naxvzh .

Comment: Have you tried a valid HTML structure? So with Doctype, Charset, ...? Maybe your browser can't interpret the '&' sign in case of a missing charset and desolves it... (just a conjecture)